# How can I install Windows XP Tablet components?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-tabletpc

I've got an HP tablet computer from around 2005 ish.

[image]

I can't find the install CD anywhere. So, I have an MSDN license, I grabbed the MSDN Windows XP Tablet Edition 2005 (CD's 1 and 2).

CD 1 is more or less, Windows XP Pro. Install was fine.

CD 2 has the Tablet PC and Media Centre components.

I Have no idea how to install the Tablet PC components. There's no setup or installer or bat.

Anyone have any ideas?

(You would have thought the MSDN CD's would have been enough).

Comment: What are the executables on the CD?

Comment: There are none. lots of files of course. a few cabs ...

Comment: Is it possible that the second CD has to be installed using a .exe from the first CD?

Comment: See if there is anything referring to Tablet in Add/Remove Windows Components in Add/Remove Programs. You may have to add them using that, not sure.

Comment: Nope - there isn't. this is windows xp we're talking about here....